Handle different error message based on business logic for a single attribute
I have a single attribute in the entities table called reporting_name. I need to display two different error messages based on business logic for different sites. If validation fails for the individual entity, the error message should be "Reporting name is blank." For the legal entity, it should be "Full Legal name is blank." I'm using Rails translations for handling error messages. What’s the best way to implement this?
# en.yml

activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        entities:
          attributes:
            reporting_name:
              blank: 'Reporting Name is blank'



It would probably be better to handle the error message in the model validation itself and use I18n to translate from there.

You might want to consider the form object pattern if your validation requirements / logic start to diverge any more. The typical Rails setup of moshing everything into the model works well for prototyping but isn't alway the best setup for more complex cases.

You can use :message option (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)
validates :attribute,
  presence: {message: ->(obj, data) { 1 == 2  ? "One message" : "Other message" } }

For the sake of simplicity, I hardcoded the message strings, but you might want to replace it with I18n methods.
